# Payload getting Serialized twice?

Tags: apex, integration

So this is driving me nuts and I cannot figure out what is the issue. I am trying to make a callout to Mulesoft with a simple payload as such :

```
[{"oldAccountId":"001f000001hRtsLAAS","newAccountId":"001f000001gy34hAAA","accountName":"Master Test Merge"}]
```

Now, this is the code I have which does the construction of the payload and makes the callout :

```
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
if (mapAccMerges.size() > 0) {
  Map<String, dse_account_merge__c> mapAccountMergeEndPoints = new Map<string, dse_account_merge__c>();
  mapAccountMergeEndPoints = dse_account_merge__c.getAll();
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setEndpoint(
    'https://dse-account-merge-staging.us-w2.cloudhub.io/api/merge'
  );
  req.setHeader('client_id', '***');
  req.setHeader('client_secret', '***');
  req.setMethod('POST');
  List<MergeDetail> payload = createPayload(mapAccMerges);
  String serializedPayload = JSON.serialize(payload);
  system.debug('>>>>serializedPayload' + serializedPayload);
  req.setBody(serializedPayload);
  Http h = new Http();
  HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
  system.debug('>>>RESPONSE>>> ' + res.getBody());
}
```

}

Also, the helper functions are as follows :

```
  private List<MergeDetail> createPayload(map<string, string> mapAccMerges) {
List<MergeDetail> mergeDetails = new List<MergeDetail>();
List<Account> lstNewAccounts = new List<Account>(
  [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :mapAccMerges.keyset()]
);
for (Account newAccName : lstNewAccounts) {
  mergeDetails.add(
    new MergeDetail(
      newAccName.Name,
      mapAccMerges.get(newAccName.Id),
      newAccName.Id
    )
  );
}
system.debug('***Details are:' + mergeDetails);
return mergeDetails;
```

}

```
  private class MergeDetail {
string accountName { get; set; }
string oldAccountId { get; set; }
string newAccountId { get; set; }
public MergeDetail(string accName, string oldId, string newId) {
  this.accountName = accName;
  this.oldAccountId = oldId;
  this.newAccountId = newId;
}
```

Now this issue is that on the line which says system.debug('>>>>serializedPayload' + serializedPayload);, I can see that the result is

```
[23]|DEBUG|>>>>serializedPayload[{"oldAccountId":"001f000001hRuFAAA0","newAccountId":"001f000001gy34hAAA","accountName":"Master Test Merge"}]
```

However, at Mulesoft's end, it is being received like this :

```
[{\"oldAccountId\":\"001f000001hRuFAAA0\",\"newAccountId\":\"001f000001gy34hAAA\",\"accountName\":\"Master Test Merge\"}]": null
}
```

Could someone please tell me if Im missing something?

Comment: This could be useful - make sure Mulesoft knows that you are sending JSON. `req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Comment: @CasparHarmer You are freakking force of nature! Bang on man. Please post your comment as the answer. Ill select it. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Ok! I didn't put as an answer before because I thought it was an outside chance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Mulesoft doesn't know you are sending it JSON.

Try adding this header:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Hope that helps ;)